# 'Invariants' in a category of modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, modules, invariance, additive-categories

I have a commutative unital ring $R$, a full additive subcategory $\mathcal{C}$ of $\text{Mod}_R$ that is closed under isomorphisms and an operation $f \colon \mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C}) \to \mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$ with the following properties:

1. If $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic objects in $\mathcal{C}$, then $f(A)=f(B)$.
2. $f(A\oplus B)=f(A)+f(B)$ for all objects $A$, $B$ in $\mathcal{C}$.

Is there a widely accepted name for such an operation? I have a number of examples of these that I am using to classify objects in such a category $\mathcal{C}$ by their direct sum representations.

PS: No object in $\mathcal{C}$ can be written as an infinite sum of non-zero $R$-modules.

Comment: Such operations $f$ are not interesting in many cases, because the fact that $A \oplus B$ is isomorphic to $B$ for $B=A \oplus A \oplus A \oplus ...$ (the direct sum of infinitely many copies of $A$) implies that $f(A)$ must be zero.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang In my case, if $\oplus_{\mathbb{N}}A\in\mathcal{C}$, then $A$ is zero object

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang While the Eilenberg-swindle is a valid point of concern I would not say that such operations are uninteresting in general. Isn’t this kind of stuff basically what K-theory is about?

Comment: Is the $A$ in properties 1. and 2. the same as the ring $A$ or is it just some element of $\mathcal C$? Anyways, I don't know of any official name for these things but I'd imagine if you called this "an additive invariant on $\mathcal C$" people would understand. I will note however that the term "additive invariant" could also be interpreted as being additive more generally on short exact sequences

Comment: @paulblartmathcop Thanks for pointing that out, the ring $A$ (now $R$) and the object $A$ are not the same.

Comment: @JonasLinssen $K$-Theory mainly concerns sequences of functors from some concrete category to the category of abelian groups so far as I understand it, so would not include what I describe above

Comment: I'd say that invariants which are additive on short exact sequences are both more widely used and more widely studied. And these kinds of invariants do relate to $K$-theory quite closely, more specifically to $K_0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "invariant" is often used for a function which maps isomorphic objects to the same thing. And the second property is commonly called additivity. Hence, as already said in the comments, "additive invariant" is a proper name for this, maybe even "$\mathbb{N}$-valued additive invariant". But just to be sure, when you use this somewhere, better add the definition. Also notice that what you describe is the same as an additive functor $\mathcal{C}_{\cong} \to \mathbb{N}$, where $\mathcal{C}_{\cong}$ is the core of $\mathcal{C}$.